# Windows: watch open directory requests (without IFS)

Tags: windows, winapi, directory, monitoring

Without using IFS, is there a way to listen in on open directory requests?  I'm looking specifically for requests made through Explorer to see which directories on a local machine users are opening up so that supplemental information can be supplied from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section on MSDN may be a good idea for the start.

Comment: Arty, thanks for the reply but can you answer two quick follow-up questions: 1) have you ever implemented anything similar in a project, and 2) does the article directly address the question in my post or did you just write it because there "may be" something worthwhile in there but you're not really sure?

Comment: Hi! I on of my projects which I led and designed in this company (www.invisiblecrm.com) was about managing local filesystem as a database (the product is SalesFolder, I was chief architect back then - http://bit.ly/zAl8z1). Our options of integration were: 1) leaving user with NTFS and track its changes; 2) implement Windows Shell Namespace (and break compatibility with non-native file browsing interface, like that in java-based apps, or Far, for instance); 3) implement IFS (that might produce a lot of maintenance). So we picked tracking NTFS, but I experimented with shell NS, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and professional reply, Arty.  I'll read over the article.

Comment: You are welcome. Although, I think writing NS extension may be too much for simply tracking the directories opening sequence. I'm concerned, will look though shell integration documentation tomorrow. BTW, are you going to be WinXP-compatible or Vista+ only?

Comment: WinXP would be nice but it's not critical.  I'll just be relieved if I can use a non-IFS solution at this point.  I've done some IFS but it's messy, difficult to debug and is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an ideal candidate for a shell extension that will be part of Explorer and can show this additional information when they browse.

Comment: Hi Deanna, although the shell extension handlers don't seem to specifically handle directory changes (from what I could find), it does have some nifty ideas like infotips.  Do you have any information that can provide dealing with whenever a user changes the directory in Explorer?